# How can I summon a minecart and have the player automatically enter it when spawned in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a rollercoaster and attempting to add a button that makes a command block summon the Minecart onto the tracks and has the player automatically enter it.

I am using Minecraft Bedrock (specifically Windows 10) on 1.16.

Answer (score 1):

When doing this you could use the possible commands:

```
/ride @a[tag=example] summon_ride minecart

/execute@e[tag=example] ~~~ tp @p @e[type=minecart]
```

(i'm not a full expert on the ride command but that command should solve your problem if this did not solve your problem please let me know) :)

Comment: Could you add an explanation of what each command does, and what [tag=example] is doing? I know, but it would help others with similar (but not identical) problems.